# Beginner Question: Normalization

Tags: normalization

We know that we can normalize 1NF to 2NF by removing the partial dependencies. But I saw a lot of examples only show partial dependencies with 1 one of the PKs. If a table (in 1NF) has 3 PKs, and there is an attribute that is partially dependent on 2 of the 3PKs (different than the usual example which only depends on 1 of the PKs), how should I normalize the table to 2NF?